# How to create angular component in vue 3 js?

Tags: angular, vuejs3

i am trying to create angular component by running command ng gc componentName but am getting error like it is outside angular cli

Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace --getting this error even though i installed angular in vue project

Comment: Run the command on the root folder. 'src' folder or path where you have package.json file

Comment: Why do you have an Angular app in a Vuejs project? They are both separate frameworks, ideally you should only be using one of them.

Comment: @MuhammadKamran i need to integrate angular app in Vue js , any suggestions for that